# Replacement of rdf:aboutEachPrefix

Tags: rdf, semantic-web

RDF/XML used to contain a `rdf:aboutEachPrefix` attribute that indicated that a description applies to all resources that share a prefix of the URIs. It was eventually removed, as a serialization format was a wrong place for this type of information.

However, I find storing this kind of information still useful. Abusing the attribute as a property, I might want to represent something like:

```
[
  rdf:aboutEachPrefix "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" ;
  rdfs:isDefinedBy <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
] . # all things under owl: are defined by owl:

[
  rdf:aboutEachPrefix "http://example.org/people/" ;
  a :Person
] . # all resources here are people

[
  rdf:aboutEachPrefix "urn:isbn:" ;
  a :Book
] . # all things with an ISBN are books

[
  rdf:aboutEachPrefix "mailto:" ;
  a :EmailAddress
] . # only identifies e-mail addresses
```

So, is there a vocabulary that can be used for expressing statements about a range of URIs in this manner? Something like linking the prefix to a class would be fine, as OWL can do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

The property `log:uri` is a possible way to express the relation between an entity and a URI is it identified by:

> This allows one to look at the actual string of the URI which identifies this. (Cwm can get the URI of a resource or get the resource from the URI.)
> This is a level breaker, breaking the rule of not looking inside a
> URI.   Use (eg with  string:match) to replace RDF's old "aboutEach"
> functionality. Use to implement the URI spec and protocol specs, etc.

Any reasoner that supports it could materialize such a predicate for any URI node:

```
<urn:isbn:1> log:uri "urn:isbn:1"^^xsd:anyURI .
```

Then all that remains is to express the restriction on this property (with OWL for example):

```
[
  a owl:Restriction ;
  owl:onProperty log:uri ;
  owl:someValuesFrom [
    a rdfs:Datatype ;
    owl:onDatatype xsd:anyURI ;
    owl:withRestrictions (
      [ xsd:pattern "urn:isbn:.*" ]
    )
  ]
] rdfs:subClassOf :Book .
```